# Wpf binding to class with unknown properties count

Tags: wpf, binding

I have class Products with unknown numbers of properties such as "Name", "Price" and so on. I retreive them only when parsing some txt file.

How should I:

1. write a Product class to emplement dynimicly adding Properies
2. Bind this collection of Products with unknonwn numbers of properties to ListView in XAML (or should I build  in code behind after parsing txt file?)

Comment: Do you expect the values of these properties to change, and want the ListView to update itself accordingly? Or are these Products readonly?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a `Dictionary<string, object>` to store the property names and associated values.
2. You need to generate the columns dynamically in code-behind, based on the keys in the dictionary. You can bind to a specific item of a dictionary using a binding path like `"Properties[SomeKey]"` (assuming your dictionary is called `Properties`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Thomas for a quick answer.
 - I make Dictionary where object is `List<string>`
 - Im trying to Bind to GridView but no result
just this Test emlementation works  but of course this not that I want
what I should write in:

- Grid1.DataContext
- listView1.ItemsSource
- gvc.DisplayMemberBinding

_

```
enter code here

_importView = new Views.ImportBomView();
        _importView.Grid1.DataContext = _dynimicList;
        _importView.listView1.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)_dynimicList.PropsDict["Value"];
        foreach (var item in _dynimicList.PropsDict.Keys)
        {
            GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
            gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding();
            gvc.Header = item;
            gvc.Width = 100;

            _importView.gridView1.Columns.Add(gvc);
        }

        _importView.Show();
```